# PDF transformation matrix has a scaling of 50 units

Tags: pdf, pdf-parsing

I'm trying to highlight some text with a glyph width of 1000 (which corresponds to 1 unit of text space)and font size of 1; the transformation matrix is [50 0 0 50 0 0]. The result is text that is too big. But this is not the case. The text that is being displayed is not big at all; it's a normal size.

Any PDF reader I open the file with has no problems highlighting the word, which means that I'm missing something somewhere.

Currently I'm checking for the default font and the font array in the fonts dictionary, the font size, and the transformation matrix. Is there any other way to scale text in a PDF besides the ones I just mentioned?

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question. A few possibility coming to my mind immediately: A new transformation matrix (argument to **cm**) does not replace the old one; instead it is multiplied to it (from the left). In case of **q** ... **Q** you have to consider resets of the current transformation matrix. Furthermore there is the test matrix to consider. Finally the **UserUnit** of the page might change the rules.

Comment: I didn't verify the cm operator at all. I'm currently adding support to it. However, I still don't understand q and Q operators. What is exactly saved in the graphics state stack? The CTM?

Comment: *What is exactly saved in the graphics state stack? The CTM?* - The ctm, line widths, colors, overprint settings, and much, much more. To get an impression, have a look at the entries in tables 57 and 58 of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). At least all the properties described there are part of the graphics state and, therefore, saved during **q** and restored during **Q**.

Comment: Don't forget to look at Note 2 in section 9.4.4 Text Space Details, which shows the whole set of matrix transforms to render text into user space.

Comment: @mkl Thank you! It's working fine now. I thought the only thing I had to look at were the text positioning operators. One more thing, would you mind writing your comments as an answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer combines the comments to the original question:*

> Currently I'm checking for the default font and the font array in the fonts dictionary, the font size, and the transformation matrix. Is there any other way to scale text in a PDF besides the ones I just mentioned?

A few possibility coming to my mind immediately:

- A new transformation matrix (argument to **cm**) does not replace the old one; instead it is multiplied to it (from the left).
- In case of **q** ... **Q** you have to consider resets of the current transformation matrix.

  (The current transformation matrix, line widths, colors, overprint settings, and much, much more are part of the graphics state. To get an impression, have a look at the entries in tables 57 and 58 of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). At least all the properties described there are part of the graphics state and, therefore, saved during **q** and restored during **Q**.)
- Furthermore there is the text matrix to consider.
- Finally the **UserUnit** entry of the page might change the rules.

So there's more *to look at than the text positioning operators.*

For a good overview have a look at section 9.4.4 *Text Space Details* of the PDF specification, especially *Note 2* therein. *(Thanks to @plinth.)*